# Json string to realm objects, fastest way

Tags: android, json, realm

I have the following code that I am running in an AsyncTask. It works well but the following lines seem to make it 3-5 seconds slower when used. Is there a faster way to convert my json string into realm?

```
    //Load the local model data. params[0].toString() is a json string loaded from SharedPreferences.
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject o = (JsonObject)jsonParser.parse(params[0].toString());

    Realm realmThread = Realm.getInstance(visnetawrap.appModel);

    //work orders, total entries of 4000.
    JsonArray openWorkOrders = o.getAsJsonArray("work_orders");

    //Convert the lists so they can be used with realm.
    List<OpenOrderObject> woList = visnetawrap.gsonClient.fromJson(openWorkOrders.toString(), new TypeToken<List<OpenOrderObject>>() {
    }.getType());
    realmThread.beginTransaction();
    realmThread.copyToRealm(woList);
    realmThread.commitTransaction();
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how well your JSON match your model classes. In the above code, you seems to do a lot of extra work converting between a string representation and a object model 2 times.

If you model matches your JSON 1:1 you can just use `realm.createAllFromJson(OpenOrderObject.class, openWorkOrders)`. You don't have to convert it first using GSON unless GSON manipulates the input somehow. You can see more here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#createAllFromJson-java.lang.Class-org.json.JSONArray-.

Also, it shouldn't really take seconds to parse this if your input is fairly small (which I guess it is since you are saving it in SharedPreferences), but note that Realm transactions are blocking, so if you have multiple background threads doing transactions they will block each other.

Comment: Christian, thank you for your answer. I will test it out and see if this helps. I narrowed it down to this line of code from above: List<OpenOrderObject> woList = visnetawrap.gsonClient.fromJson(openWorkOrders.toString(), new TypeToken<List<OpenOrderObject>>() {
    }.getType()); It seems you are saying this is unnecessary, I will get back to you soon.

Comment: Not to sound rude or anything but is Realm slow for Android or am I just using it wrong? I tried doing a fetchAll and it took over 20 seconds. I did have about 4k objects though. I noticed realm runs great on iOS but only 64 bit devices.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing something wrong. All our benchmarks have us faster than raw SQLite. I would suggest making an issue on our GitHub page so we can investigate it further: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues

Comment: I just want to update you and say I could not use createAllFromJson. I am using retrofit to get my json combined with gson converter. When I use createAllFromJson it seems to create the objects but when I do queries nothing ever gets returned, not sure why. The json matches the object model but I use serializename so i assume that is why I need to use gson first?